# Elliptic points in Sage

Tags: function, sage

I would like to find elliptic points of congruence subgroups `Gamma(N)`, `Gamma_1(N)`, etc., using Sage.  I know there is simple function in MAGMA (`EllipticPoints(G)`) but can't find anything similar in Sage. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sage has functions `Gamma`, `Gamma0`, `Gamma1` to define congruence subgroups of the modular group.

Given such a group, the methods `nu2` and `nu3` give the number of
elliptic points of order 2 and of order 3 of this group.

```py
sage: G = Gamma0(13)
sage: G.nu2()
2
sage: G.nu3()
2
```

The methods `ncusps`, `index`, `genus` give the number of cusps,
index, genus of a congruence group.

```py
sage: G.ncusps()
2
sage: G.index()
14
sage: G.genus()
0
```

The Magma documentation you are referring to might be this:
https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1554.

In which case you want the actual elliptic points in the
upper half-plane. Here is a way to get them.

Define the function `elliptic_points` as follows.

```py
def elliptic_points(G):
    F = FareySymbol(G)
    P = F.pairings()
    if all(n > 0 for n in P):
        return []
    M = F.pairing_matrices()
    ell = []
    for k, n in enumerate(P):
        if n < 0:
            a, b, c, d = list(M[k])
            R.<x> = QQbar[]
            p = c*x^2 + (d-a)*x - b
            for r in p.roots(multiplicities=False):
                if r.imag() > 0:
                    ell.append(r)
    return ell
```

Then the following works:

```py
sage: G = Gamma0(13)
sage: ell = elliptic_points(G)

sage: ell
[0.2692307692307693? + 0.06661733875264913?*I,
 0.3846153846153846? + 0.07692307692307692?*I,
 0.6153846153846154? + 0.07692307692307692?*I,
 0.7307692307692308? + 0.06661733875264913?*I]

sage: for p in ell:
....:    print p.radical_expression()
....:
1/26*I*sqrt(3) + 7/26
1/13*I + 5/13
1/13*I + 8/13
1/26*I*sqrt(3) + 19/26
```

I could not find this function in the existing Sage code.
It might be worth adding it.